# How to create a pie chart showing in percent the occurence of factors within one column of a dataframe in R with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"))
```

I would like to create a pie chart showing that `A`, `B` and `C` all occur 33.3% of the time within the `df`. I know I can calculate the percentages separately, but is there a way within `ggplot` to do this automatically?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `table` and `pie` in base R:

```
pie(table(df$a))

# or fancier, to include percentages:
pie(table(df$a), 
    labels = paste0(names(table(df$a)), " (", round(prop.table(table(df$a))*100, 2), "%)"))
```

[image]

I'm not particularly prolific in `ggplot`, but expanding on [making a basic pie chart](https://r-graph-gallery.com/piechart-ggplot2.html), you could use `dplyr::count()` to modify your original data piped into the `ggplot` function and use `scales::percent` as the label:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df %>% count(a), aes(x="", y = n, fill = a)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(as.matrix(prop.table(table(a))))),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "y", start = 0) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: magic `pie`, cool!

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding magic indeed :)

Comment: @starski - see if the `ggplot` edit is what you were looking for?

Comment: As a Czech base R proponent, I basically couldn't be happier with your first solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want to precalculate the percentage you could use a factor to your x aesthetic and `fill` the column as a factor to have them as one stacked bar. After that use `coord_polar` to make it a piechart like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
df |>
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(1), fill=factor(a))) +
  geom_bar(width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: But using ```factor``` still shows the count and not the percentage, I guess I will just have to calculate the percentages.